# python read in x lines then process them and read in y more

Tags: python

I have a 2 column tsv file something like (the actual one is much longer) :

| ntxt | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | space delim string 1 |
| 0001 | space delim string 2 |
| 0001 | space delim string 3 |
| 0001 | space delim string 4 |
| 0001 | space delim string 5 |
| 0002 | space delim string 6 |
| 0002 | space delim string 7 |
| 0003 | space delim string 8 |
| 0003 | space delim string 9 |
| 0003 | space delim string 10 |
| 0003 | space delim string 11 |

I want to 'collapse' the first column, so that the file will become :

| ntxt | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | space delim string 1, space delim string 2, space delim string 3, space delim string 4, space delim string 5 |
| 0002 | space delim string 6, space delim string 7 |
| 0003 | space delim string 8, space delim string 9, space delim string 10, space delim string 11 |

My way of doing this is to read in the first line and split on a tab; read in the next line and split on a tab, then compare line1[0] to line2[0]; if the same, read line 3, etc.

```
with open('readme.txt', r) as f:
    ln = 0
    for line in f:
        ln += 1
        split_string = line.strip().split("\t")
        numbtex1 = split_string[0]
        comment1 = split_string[1]

        line2 = f.next()
        ln += 1
        split_string_2 = line2.strip().split("\t")
        numbtex2 = split_string[0]
        comment2 = split_string[1]

        if numbtext1 == numbtext2:
            line3 = f.next()
            ln += 1
            split_string_3 = line3.strip().split("\t")
            numbtex3 = split_string[0]
            comment3 = split_string[1]
        else:
            print(numbtext1 + "\t")
            for l in ln:
                print(comment[l] + "; ")
  
            if numbtex1 == numbtex3:
                line4 = f.next()
             ...
```

But, in the original .tsv file, there can 10 or more entries with the same first column (numbtext) (these all occur consecutively. In other words, all the 0001's occur one after the other, all the 0002's occur one after the other, and so forth), so I would have to nest 10 or more if statements, and what if I come across a file with many more than 10 entries that are the same. There has to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Just remember what column 1 is, and keep accumulating columns until column 1 changes.  Dump what you have, and start over.  No `if` statements are needed.

Answer (score 3):

Try `DefaultDict from Collections`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_data = defaultdict(list)

with open('readme.txt') as f:
    heading = f.readline()
    lines = [line.strip().split("\t") for line in f]
    [new_data[i[0]].append(i[1]) for i in lines]
    for i, j in new_data.items():
        print(i, ','.join(j))
```

This will give you the below output

```
0001 space delim string 1,space delim string 2,space delim string 3,space delim string 4,space delim string 5
0002 space delim string 6,space delim string 7
0003 space delim string 8,space delim string 9,space delim string 10,space delim string 11
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.  This is basically a "report writer" pattern with one level of grouping.

```
col1 = ''
columns = []
with open('x.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.strip().split('\t')
        if parts[0] != col1:
            if col1:
                print(col1+'\t'+(', '.join(columns)))
            col1 = parts[0]
            columns = []
        columns.append( parts[1] )
if col1:
    print(col1+'\t'+(', '.join(columns)))
```

For input:

```
0001    space delim string 1
0001    space delim string 2
0001    space delim string 3
0001    space delim string 4
0001    space delim string 5
0002    space delim string 6
0002    space delim string 7
0002    space delim string 8
0002    space delim string 9
0003    space delim string 10
0003    space delim string 11
0003    space delim string 12
0003    space delim string 13
```

This produces:

```
0001    space delim string 1, space delim string 2, space delim string 3, space delim string 4, space delim string 5
0002    space delim string 6, space delim string 7, space delim string 8, space delim string 9
0003    space delim string 10, space delim string 11, space delim string 12, space delim string 13
```

Comment: The solution above, by Tim Roberts, and the solution below, by NavaneethaKrishnan, both work very well. Both process my file in 5.3 seconds. Both were posted within minutes of my original question and were posted only a very few minutes apart from each other.